# sort files in a specific format

Tags: python, sorting

i tried to sort my files in this format :

[dia0_utt0.mp4 ,dia1_utt0.mp4 ,dia2_utt0.mp4 ,dia10_utt0.mp4]

not this format:

[dia0_utt0.mp4 ,dia1_utt0.mp4 ,dia10_utt0.mp4 ,dia2_utt0.mp4 ]

and  this is the code

```py
import os
files = os.listdir("/content/drive/MyDrive/emotion/data/dev/dev_splits_complete/")
sorted_files = sorted(files, key=lambda f: int(f.split('_')[0]))
print(sorted_files)
```

and i had this error:

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'dia14'
```

thank you

Comment: @TomKarzes That would still sort `dia10` before `dia2`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JohnGordon Oops, I misread the example, I thought that's what OP wanted, but it looks like the numeric portions are intended to be sorted numerically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`natsort`](https://pypi.org/project/natsort/) module:

```
# pip install natsort
from natsort import natsorted, natsort_key

lst = ['dia0_utt0.mp4', 'dia1_utt0.mp4', 'dia2_utt0.mp4', 'dia10_utt0.mp4']

# Bad output
>>> sorted(lst)
['dia0_utt0.mp4', 'dia10_utt0.mp4', 'dia1_utt0.mp4', 'dia2_utt0.mp4']

# Same output as lst
>>> natsorted(lst)
['dia0_utt0.mp4', 'dia1_utt0.mp4', 'dia2_utt0.mp4', 'dia10_utt0.mp4']

# Using sorted with natsort_key
>>> sorted(lst, key=natsort_key)
['dia0_utt0.mp4', 'dia1_utt0.mp4', 'dia2_utt0.mp4', 'dia10_utt0.mp4']
```

Answer (score 0):

A version with `re`:

```py
import re

l = ["dia0_utt0.mp4", "dia1_utt0.mp4", "dia2_utt0.mp4", "dia10_utt0.mp4"]

l = sorted(l, key=lambda f: int(re.sub(r'\D', '', f.split('_')[0])))
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
['dia0_utt0.mp4', 'dia1_utt0.mp4', 'dia2_utt0.mp4', 'dia10_utt0.mp4']
```